# Eclipse debugger stops by itself without any throwable

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse Debugger suddenly stops not throwing anything:

```
private void openChannelsListActivity() {
    try{
        Intent gridListIntent=new Intent();
        // the pause is on the following line
        gridListIntent.setClass(this,ChannelsListActivity.class);
        startActivity(gridListIntent);
    }
    catch (Throwable e){
        ErrorMessage.outputMessageByName(
            "channels_list_activity_create",this, " While setting intent.");
        finish();
    }
}
```

The stack is:

```
DexFile.defineClass(String, ClassLoader, int, ProtectionDomain) line: not available [native method] 
DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(String, ClassLoader) line: 207  
PathClassLoader.findClass(String) line: 200 
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 551   
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 511    
PackVideo.openChannelsListActivity() line: 508
```

If I press Resume, the application goes on without any problems. The activity starts OK, but it is not normal behavior and surely means something is wrong. What is it?

The problem is not in waiting; the time from starting the app to this point is about 2 seconds.

It is not an uncaught exception; I turned them off in debugger preferences.

It is not a hidden breakpoint, I have cleaned them all off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And again it was an Eclipse bug. After some entering and leaving the Eclipse, this behaviour disappeared.

As for cleaning breakpoints, I use it always when there are some problems with breakpoints, for two years already. The problem was deeper this time - I had to enter and exit Eclipse many times - I hadn't counted, there were about 5 of them, I think. And after the last one the problem disappeared. Without the system restart, without any hand-made changes in workspace or Eclipse folders. I think, it is connected with that intellectual behaviour of the debugger, when it stops before the possible break. The Eclipse debugger is buggy and in this, very complicated part, it could be even more buggy.

Comment: Interesting. At first I thought it was an Eclipse bug as well, but now it turns out I actually had a breakpoint located on a class, which doesn't look like a breakpoint, but a `C` symbol instead. It was this breakpoint which was getting hit and I didn't recognize it. That's why JeffG's solution worked for me. Are you certain JeffG's solution didn't work for you in your scenario?

Comment: As for cleaning breakpoints, I use it always when there are some problems with breakpoints, for two years already. The problem was deeper this time - I had to enter and exit Eclipse many times - I hadn't counted, there were about 5 of them, I think. And after the last one the problem disappeared. Without the system restart, without any hand-made changes in workspace or Eclipse folders. I think, it is connected with that intellectual behaviour of the debugger, when it stops before the possible break. The Eclipse debugger is buggy and in this, very complicated part, it could be even more buggy.

Answer (score 20):

A proper solution is to go

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Debug -> Breakpoints

and then on that view click the Remove All Breakpoints button.

Seems eclipse got confused and thought there was a breakpoint where there wasn't

Comment: Interesting observation, thank you, +1, haven't met it myself. But it was not the case. It is not THE solution, or a proper solution, it is merely one of many possible solutions - better correct the header.

Comment: This worked for me, but apparently not because Eclipse got confused, but because Eclipse confused me. :) Apparently there was a breakpoint located on a class of mine, which is highlighted with a `C` symbol instead of the ordinary blue bullet.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; it was a breakpoint at the declaration of the MyActivity.java class. Apparently, a breakpoint at a class declaration shows up in the editor as a white "C" in green circle, instead of the usual blue dot. I must have fat-fingered something for the breakpoint to have been added there. I deleted the breakpoint and the debugger no longer stops there.