# Why is ThreadPoolExecutor.run() being invoked?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse debugger always blocks on ThreadPoolExecutor without any obvious exception, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290470/eclipse-debugger-always-blocks-on-threadpoolexecutor-without-any-obvious-excepti)

Eclipse continually suspends execution within run() method below at line within finally block : workDone(this);

I have not set any breakpoints here and my app seems to be working as expected.

Any pointers on why this is occuring ?

```
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

   public void run() {
        try {
            Runnable task = firstTask;
            firstTask = null;
            while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
                runTask(task);
                task = null;
            }
        } finally {
            workerDone(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: what does workerDone do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all probability your method invocation `workerDone` throws an exception, which is unhandled and bubbles up outside of the `run` method. The thread is thus brought to an abrupt end, but Eclipse lets you inspect that situation just before the exception escapes the method. That's an automatic "exception breakpoint".