# Eclipse Debugging Filter Unwanted Packages

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, filtering, breakpoints

I have been using Eclipse for 2 years for development, but this filter concept I am still struggling to understand during debugging.

I usually debug in remote port mode.

Most of the times, My Eclipse catches the break point/exception in Unwanted Packages [Packages usually from other Sources like Spring, Java ThreadPool etc..] and annoys me by bringing up the debug window.

`I would like to configure Eclipse to catch breakpoints in my package only. Just ignore any where else, don't halt them or notify me.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should help you:

```
Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Debug
```

Uncheck the following:

- `Suspend exceution on uncaught exceptions`
- `Suspend exceution on compilation errors`
- `Open popup when suspended on exception`

Click on `Apply` & then `OK`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know we can add package filters for exception breakpoints but for the normal line breakpoints, I think a long way to manually disable one by one will work,
You can look at [Eclipse Creating Expression Filter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-create-exception-filter-expression.htm) for more information.
This figure provide info ho we can open Java Exception Breakpoint, [image]

Comment: I am debugging my portlets, and some breakpoints are caught in ThreadPool class, which I don't even touch. Simply, nothing has been done from myside in that, don't even understand why are they getting caught. This is clean install FYI

Comment: I think this link can be useful [Blocling on ThreadPool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290470/eclipse-debugger-always-blocks-on-threadpoolexecutor-without-any-obvious-excepti) llok at answer posted by DeeJay